# Prevent autoloading scripts from .vim/plugin/CVS/Base/*.vim

Tags: vim, cvs, config, autoload

I use CVS to sync my config files between different PCs, including my `$HOME/.vim` folder.

But there is a problem.  CVS likes to leave old copies of files in `.vim/plugin/CVS/Base/` and Vim thinks it should load these files.  I want vim to ignore them!

Comment: I might upgrade to git if it's still popular in a decade or two.  Glad I held back on the "upgrade" to subversion.

Comment: Mercurial is easier to learn if you come from cvs. And its commands seem to be more consistent (though I am subjective here as it is the first VCS I used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SourceCmd` for this case:

```
augroup ForbidCVS
    autocmd!
    autocmd SourceCmd */CVS/* :" Do nothing
augroup END
```

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of `$HOME/.vimrc` add:

```
" Disable normal auto-loading of plugins
set noloadplugins

" Now load just the plugins we want
runtime! plugin/*.vim
```

This differs from the default behaviour which usually loads scripts from plugin/ and all its subfolders.  I suspect most users do not make sub-folders.  For users that do, this won't work!

Comment: Users don’t use subfolders a lot, but authors of complicated plugins may do. By the way, this does not fix the problem for filetype plugins: they are more unlikely to have subfolders, but `cvs` is a valid file type used for commit messages. To see problem you must meet the following requirements: version-controlled files in `ftplugin/` directory (so that they have old copies in `CVS/`), windows/mac (as they both use filesystems that ignore case) and using vim for writing commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to share your .vim and .vimrc across multiple computers is to put both on dropbox and symlink them to the $HOME directory of each computer you work on. No CVS required, and any change you make to your .vimrc for example, is immediately available to all other computers.

Another cool tip is to use the vim gsession plugin to create global session files stored to your .vim directory. So if you create a session on one computer, it is also available to all the others.

Comment: VCS are used not only for sharing configuration files across multiple computers, they are for keeping history as well.

Comment: Of course. But do you really need version control on your .vim dir and .vimrc?

Comment: @dharhan It comes handy when working on netbook that is not connected to the Internet and I edit the configuration files (merging; but that was never a strong side of CVS). And the other thing: I am absolutely sure I won’t accidently loose committed configuration: doing `rm .vimrc` on dropbox mount will spread these changes to other systems, doing the same on mercurial checkout won’t. This also happens, rarely and most of time with the symlinks in $HOME instead of actually used files, but does. For me undo such removal in mercurial repository is much simpler then to get files from the backup.

Comment: If you are as good at breaking plugins as me, then yes you need revision history!  But thanks for the dropbox tip, I know some people find that approach works.